# Can Bamboo C.I Server be configured to show workspace like Jenkins?

Tags: bamboo

I am wondering if there is a panel that shows the source code of the project being run, because Jenkins C.I server has this, so I am wondering if Bamboo has it also.

Answer (score 3):

With Bamboo, its possible to browse the files on the file system if the build has run on the same machine as the server from any job result.

Do you want to browse the source or just want to get at files created by the build? If its the latter, you can capture any files from the working directory using [Artifacts](http://confluence.atlassian.com/x/DghTE).

Comment: Over a year since this was answered but giving it a shot. "its possible to browse the files on the file system"... how?

Comment: I think what jdumay means is that you can log on to the build agent that ran the build and view the files there.... not via the Bamboo Web UI.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can view the source and build output is to log on to the Bamboo agent that ran the build.  You can get the information you need from the first two lines of the log for each job:

```
simple  15-Apr-2015 18:28:52    Build My Projects - Foo - Build and Test #95 (MP-FOO-JOB1-95) started building on agent bamboo-slave1
simple  15-Apr-2015 18:28:53    Build working directory is /opt/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MP-FOO-JOB1
```

So in the above case, you would log on to bamboo-slave1 and

```
cd /opt/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/MP-FOO-JOB1
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread... but what I want to do is exactly this. The thing is my company has moved over to a Bamboo server which is centralized. We do not have access the physical server. Using Jenkins we did but we didn't need to as we could use the Jenkins UI to view the current workspace where files were checked out to. Is there no way to view the sources files, for example what was checked out from bitbucket, using the Bamboo UI itself?

Comment: @Chrispie only by adding a shell task to your build job that runs the necessary commands.  For example on a Unix system you could just run "ls -lR".  You would then see the results in the build log.